# When is 着ける used in context of clothes? (eg in comparison to 着る, する、履く)

Tags: word-choice

I recently read that:

> 着る（きる）is used for the wearing clothes for either the upper half of the body (eg 上着）or the whole body in general.
>
> 履く（はく）is used for bottom half (eg shoes, socks, trousers).
>
> する　is used for accessories (watch, scarf etc)

Is there are a specific/common use for 着ける (つける） or the type of clothes/accessories that take this verb?

Comment: On top of user1205935's 巻く, 被{かぶ}る is usually used for hats and はめる for gloves. I might be missing others too.

Comment: @dainichi: Tx. I　did not know はめる but　I see it goes for rings aswell as gloves. The only other one I remember is 眼鏡を掛ける。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

着ける can be used for those items that fall under the する "used for accessories" category above, e.g.

> 時計を着ける
>   イヤリングを着ける.

Probably the reading comes from 付ける »to attach« and the *kanji* from the fact that you are "attaching" something to your body in the sense of wearing it.

By the way, マフラーを巻く would be preferred to マフラーを着ける or マフラーをする.

Comment: I'd say it's more common to say 時計をする than 時計を着ける (but only marginally, because younger generations just don't wear a watch!)

Comment: つける in the context of wearing something, is it always 着ける? Or does it sometimes correspond to a different kanji?